# A control with ID could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel- COMMAND ARGUMENT WORKAROUND

Tags: vb.net, updatepanel, repeater, scriptmanager

Here's an update panel with triggers:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
   <ContentTemplate>
      <p> Much wow! </p>
   </ContentTemplate>
   <Triggers>
   <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID='x' EventName="Command" />
   </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This is my repeater (NOT INSIDE THE UPDATE PANEL):

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="x" OnCommand="x_command" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("y") %>'>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I am unable to find the controlID of the linkbutton.
I've tried registering the control, the control gets registered but the updatepanel still cannot find the control.

Code to register control-

```
Protected Sub Repeater1_ItemDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles Repeater1.ItemDataBound
   Dim lb As LinkButton = TryCast(e.Item.FindControl("dude1"), LinkButton)
   ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Me).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(lb)
   Response.Write("afa")
End Sub
```

Comment: I've been stuck for days and would gladly appreciate any help/suggestion.

Comment: Is there any other way I could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized- all I didn't have to do was define the button as trigger in the update panel.
When you register it as an asyncpostback control, it already acts as a trigger.

Hope this helps anyone that got stuck.